# Regarding gettimeofday shared memory access in user space.

Tags: linux, time, kernel, gettimeofday

I am trying to implement implement one approach to access the gettimeofday in user land emulator and need all possible pointers. I'm trying to map a read only region from Kernel space to User space (64 Bit) in which user space can directly poll and read the gettimeofday () value without much overhead. It is similar to the VSYSCALL/VDSO implementation but here I am trying to have one dedicated program to fetch the content of the memory (VDSO shared page) from user space instead of using the function pointer or *gettimeofday wrapper.

Current Flow:

Emulator -> Gettimeofday -> Trap -> Emulate() -> GLIBC -> update the time struct() -> back to Emulator

Trying to achieve :
Kernel/TSC/TImer -> update time_memory();

Emulator -> Gettimeofday -> read time_memory();

First, I'm not 100% sure how logical it is to think something like this but still I feel it's doable by some means..

I came across the below link, but still need more (or) any possible information to proceed further.

http://lwn.net/Articles/9266/

Platform : Linux
Arch     : PowerpC
Kernel   : 2.6.34

Thanks in Advance.